# Android - InputStream is always died on foreground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, inputstream, saxparser

I have an application, it will parse data from Youtube's playlist, the data is formatted like XML. I am using SAXParser to do this. But having a issue when using InputStream with SAXParser.

```
SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(this);
URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(pURL).openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();/*always die here*/
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
```

The class that contains code is extending DefaultHandler.
With this code, if I run with `class DataASyn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` it is ok and run well, but when I run without DataAsyn, it is always died as I described above. I do not know why ????
I also debug when on background, and recognize that at `InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();` program will pause some seconds before continuing run, maybe it was waiting for data ?!?
I hope all information above, anyone will know what has happened and give me any ideas about it.

Thanks, 
Ryan

Comment: which version of android are you running this on? and when you say it "dies" do you mean ANR (crashes Application Not Responding)?

Comment: I am using Android 4.0.3 with Samsung Galaxy S2. "Dies" I mean like your post - Crash appears!

Answer (score 0):

The fact it works in your async task and "dies" otherwise, might mean your getting the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception).  When the code executes in the AsyncTask it does so on a different thread other than the UI-Thread.  When you run this code outside the AsyncTask, presumably your UI-Thread, this exception will get thrown on android 3.0+ if I remember correctly.

Also, getting the input stream from any endpoint will take some time as it is a network operation.  Don't expect it to be another instantaneous when stepping through it with breakpoints.